# Jquery bubbling event on window resize - responsive design

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, window-resize

I am using responsive design and I want to add a dropdow function with Jquery on a click event only when the screen is less than 1020px. I'm using the resize function which is trigger when the customer change the size of his browser window.

But the problem is that the function is bubbling and run 5 times. How is that possible???

```
$(window).resize(function() {

   var screenWindow = $j(document).width();

   if(screenWindow < 1020){
       $('.filter').click(function(){                           
          $('dd.first').slideToggle();
       });
   }
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('.filter').click(function() {
     if( $(window).width() < 1020 ) {
         $('dd.first').slideToggle();         
     }
     return false;
});
```

put this outside of resize

Also how many 'dd' and how many '.filter' are there on the page? Can you show some html?
If you have multiple .filter then the click handler will run multiple times. If the 'dd' is inside the filter then the code can change so that only that 'dd' is triggered

Comment: I've tested the timer option which make sense. But it was only working the first time around. I had a big window, resize and click on the element: it work all fine. But when I resize again it begin to open and close several time.  The option to check the size of the window inside the click function solved it. Thank eveybody for the very quick feedback!!